# ANTLR: grammar for the R5RS lexical structure, problem with numbers

Tags: numbers, scheme, antlr, grammar, r5rs

i'm implementing an IDE for scheme in eclipse using DLTK. So far, i am programming the grammar to recognize the lexical structure.

i'm following the official EBNF which can be viewed here:
http://rose-r5rs.googlecode.com/hg/doc/r5rs-grammar.html

i can't get a simple form of the numbers grammar getting worked. for example the decimal numbers, i have

```
grammar r5rsnumbers;

options {
  language = Java;
}


program:
NUMBER;

// NUMBERS


NUMBER : /*NUM_2 | NUM_8 |*/ NUM_10; //| NUM_16;
fragment NUM_10 : PREFIX_10 COMPLEX_10;
fragment COMPLEX_10 
: REAL_10 (
            '@' REAL_10
            | '+' (
                    UREAL_10 'i'
                    | 'i'
                    )?  
            | '-' (
                    UREAL_10 'i'
                    | 'i'
                    )?
            )?
    | '+' (
        UREAL_10 'i'
        | 'i'
        )?  
    | '-' (
        UREAL_10 'i'
        | 'i'
        )?;

fragment REAL_10 : SIGN UREAL_10;
fragment UREAL_10 
    : UINTEGER_10 ('/' UINTEGER_10)?
    | DECIMAL_10;
fragment UINTEGER_10 : DIGIT_10+ '#'*;

fragment DECIMAL_10 
    : UINTEGER_10 SUFFIX
    | '.' DIGIT_10+ '#'* SUFFIX
    | DIGIT_10+ '.' DIGIT_10* '#'* SUFFIX
    | DIGIT_10+ '#'+ '.' '#'* SUFFIX;

fragment PREFIX_10 
    : RADIX_10  EXACTNESS
    | EXACTNESS RADIX_10;

fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
fragment EMPTY : '""'; // empty is the empty string
fragment SUFFIX : EMPTY | EXPONENT_MARKER SIGN DIGIT_10+;
fragment EXPONENT_MARKER : 'e' | 's' | 'f' | 'd' | 'l';
fragment SIGN : EMPTY | '+' |  '-';
fragment EXACTNESS : EMPTY | '#i' | '#e';
fragment RADIX_10 : EMPTY | '#d';
fragment DIGIT_10 : DIGIT;
```

the problem is, it is not recognizing anything. i don't understand the warning i get from the PREFIX_10 or how to solve it. if i don't use fragment in the rules, the file isn't compiling since he complains about the DIGIT_10 rule matching the same input as almost all other prior rules.

it's the same with num_2, num_8 and num_16

plus, i am not sure with my solution of the empty-string.

how do i get around here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your ANTLR rule:

```
EMPTY : '""';
```

does not match an empty string, but two double quotes.

But you don't want a lexer rule to match *only* an empty string: that will cause it to go in an infinite loop since there are an infinite amount of empty strings in any string/source.

So the BNF rules:

```
<real 10>
    ::= <sign> <ureal 10>

<sign>
    ::= <empty> | {+} | {-}
```

should *not* be translated as the following ANTLR rules:

```
REAL_10 
  :  SIGN UREAL_10
  ;

SIGN 
  :  EMPTY 
  |  '+' 
  |  '-'
  ;
```

but like this instead:

```
REAL_10 
  :  SIGN? UREAL_10
  ;

SIGN 
  :  '+' 
  |  '-'
  ;
```

Also note that your rule:

```
fragment COMPLEX_10 
: REAL_10 (
            '@' REAL_10
            | '+' (
                    UREAL_10 'i'
                    | 'i'
                    )?  
            | '-' (
                    UREAL_10 'i'
                    | 'i'
                    )?
            )?
    | '+' (
        UREAL_10 'i'
        | 'i'
        )?  
    | '-' (
        UREAL_10 'i'
        | 'i'
        )?;
```

is a bit hard to read. Indenting it differently might make this a bit easier to comprehend:

```
fragment COMPLEX_10
  :  REAL_10 ( '@' REAL_10 
             | '+' (UREAL_10 'i' | 'i')? 
             | '-' (UREAL_10 'i' | 'i')?
             )?
  |  '+' (UREAL_10 'i' | 'i')?  
  |  '-' (UREAL_10 'i' | 'i')?
  ;
```

which could be simplified by writing:

```
fragment COMPLEX_10
  :  REAL_10 ('@' REAL_10)?
  |  REAL_10? ('+' | '-') UREAL_10? 'i'
  ;
```

Also be aware that many BNF notations make no distinction between lower- and uppercase literals. So instead of writing `'i'` in your ANTLR grammar, you might want to use `('i' | 'I')` instead.

### EDIT

> ***Sebastian wrote:***
>
> but i'm still having problems with the `PREFIX_10` rule: `fragment PREFIX_10 : RADIX_10? EXACTNESS? | EXACTNESS? RADIX_10?;` which tells me that alternative 2 can never be matched, although it should match `#i #d` and `#d #i` with the 2 alternatives seperately or am i doing something wrong here?

There are a couple of things wrong with the (fragment) rule `PREFIX_10`:

```java
fragment PREFIX_10 
  :  RADIX_10? EXACTNESS? // alternative 1
  |  EXACTNESS? RADIX_10? // alternative 2
  ;
```

For one, both match an empty string. Because alternative 1 will *always* match an empty string, alternative 2 would never match, which is what ANTLR was telling you.

Now, looking at the BNF rules:

```
<exactness>
    ::= <empty> | {#i} | {#e}

<prefix 10>
    ::= <radix 10> <exactness>
      | <exactness> <radix 10>

<radix 10>
    ::= <empty> {#d}
```

*(Note that `<empty> {#d}` equals `{#d}`, so the `<empty>` is IMO just misplaced. All other radii don't have and `<empty>` part)*

I'd translate those into the following (*untested!*) ANTLR rules:

```
fragment EXACTNESS
  :  '#i' 
  |  '#e'
  ;

fragment PREFIX_10
  :  RADIX_10 EXACTNESS?
  |  EXACTNESS RADIX_10 // **
  ;

fragment RADIX_10
  :  '#d'
  ;
```

****** Note that it's **not**:

```
fragment PREFIX_10
  :  RADIX_10 EXACTNESS? // matches '#d'
  |  EXACTNESS? RADIX_10 // matches '#d'
  ;
```

because the lexer does not know through which alternative to match `#d`.

And in case the BNF rule for `<radix 10>` should be like this (ie. they forgot to place a `|`):

```
<radix 10>
    ::= <empty> 
      | {#d}
```

then the ANTLR `PREFIX_10` should still look like:

```
fragment PREFIX_10
  :  RADIX_10 EXACTNESS?
  |  EXACTNESS RADIX_10
  ;
```

but then all other rules that use `PREFIX_10` should make `PREFIX_10` optional.

HTH

Comment: thanks for your answer! but i'm still having problems with the PREFIX_10 rule:
`fragment PREFIX_10 
    : RADIX_10?  EXACTNESS?
    | EXACTNESS? RADIX_10?;` which tells me that alternative 2 can never be matched, although it should match `#i #d` and `#d #i` with the 2 alternatives seperately or am i doing something wrong here?